# LONG TERM SCHEDULER and how does it interact with USER

Tags: operating-systems, os-kernel

If I select chrome browser, then I select Android Studio, do they directly open in Ready Queue (allocated to RAM main memory), what processes actually goes into job queue? Does Job Queue gets filled when RAM has no space available? What I want to ask basically is if I opened a word processor and a browser, do these processors are first there in job queue and then ready queue, or directly in ready queue?

I know Windows and UNIX have almost done away with LONG TERM SCHEDULER but consider a general interactive OS.

Comment: When the RAM has no space available, a certain part of the hard drive is used as an "extra RAM". It will be slower, but can allow to use extra ram above the limit, when you need it.

Comment: So does long term scheduler manages the job queue in that extra ram? And does it job is to send process from extra RAM to main RAM